# mongo shell query not working for nested documents

Tags: mongodb, mongo-shell

I am new to MongoDB and I need help with one basic operation that I am trying. Below is how my mongo collection is structured,

```
{
    id: "<some_id>",
    field1: ["value1", "value2", "value3"],
    field2:[
        field-a {
            id: <some_id>,
            field-a-1: <some_string>,
            field-a-2: [<some_value>, <some_value>]
        },
        field-b {
            id: <some_id>,
            field-b-1: <some_string>,
            field-b-2: [<some_value>, <some_value>]
        },
        field-c {
            id: <some_id>,
            field-c-1: <some_string>,
            field-c-2: [<some_value>, <some_value>]
        },
        field-d {
            id: <some_id>,
            field-d-1: <some_string>,
            field-d-2: [<some_value>, <some_value>]
        },
    ]
}
```

I want to get the document from “field2" which has id === <requested_id>

I am trying it via mongo shell and below is the query that I am using.

```
db.posts.find({'field2.id': {$eq:'<some_id>'}})
```

It is not working. It returns all the documents of the field2 array and I don’t want that.

Comment: if you know its unique id and having only one document, then try project part  `db.posts.find({'field2.id': {$eq:'<some_id>'}}, {"field2.$": 1})` this will return only one matching document from array

Comment: Thanks a lot, @turivishal. It worked. Can you recommend me a resource to understand the queries better?
I tried something similar but I didn't try .$ as you have in {"field2.$": 1}. If you can brief me on the significance of this,  it will be really helpful.

Comment: see [projection-positional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#definition), The `$` operator projects the first matching array element from each document in a collection based on some condition from the query statement.

Comment: @turivishal The same query is not working with NodeJs driver. If I use it as shown below, it returns all the documents in the collection.


      collection.find({ 'posts.id': req.body.id}, { 'posts.$': 1})
      .forEach((doc) => {
        console.log(doc);
        res.json(doc.posts).status(200);
      });

Comment: can someone help me with the nodejs equivalent of the same query?

Comment: update your question with details: add exact document that you have in collection, expected result from that document.